# Jquery add blank space

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a blank space in the following.

```
$('.post_name'+post_id+'').hide();
```

So it will render something similar to

> post_name 8

I tried adding '' and " " but they don;t work. Can someone please help me?

Comment: A className can not have a space in it. Nor can it start with a number (in case you were trying to select an element with both classes, which would require a different selector anyway).

Comment: fyi '8' would be an invalid selector in jQuery and '.8' or '#8' would be invalid attributes (they can't start with numerals)

Comment: Thanks! I'll just use id and class for the div then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$('.post_name ' + post_id)
```

Result will be like `post_name 8`

Make sure that your selector works in such format :) Let's know if you have any problems with the selector.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried but still no go :( What I'm doing is  retrieving the id from a div and passing it to a class name


<code>
('.edit').click(function()
{
var cat_id = $(this).attr("id"); //get link ID

$('.cat_name ' +cat_id+'').hide();
</code>

the cat name_name div is for example "Sports 8" and if I could achieve a blank space in the js the class should hide()

It works however without blankspaces "Sports8" but I need teh space to style the div name and also have unique numbers

Comment: nvm, I'll just put the data in an id and use class to style elements the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
selector = 'post_name '+post_id;
$(selector).hide();
```

That might make it a little more extensible.